# head file with windows line endings

Tags: linux, awk, sed, head

On my ContOS server, I have several huge files with windows line endings.  Which, I need the first `n` lines from in order to run some tests.

I've tried a few standard "linux" ways of doing it:

```
head -10 file.dat
```

And

```
sed -n 1,10p file.dat
```

And

```
awk 'NR <=10' file.dat
```

All of which produce don't respect the windows line endings and simply output the entire file.

**Is there a way to get the `n` lines of a file with windows line endings?**

Also, it should be noted that the output should still have the windows line endings.

Comment: Windows line endings contain *nix line endings within them, so would not do what you describe.

Comment: Try removing the Control M characters by doing `tr -d < Input_file > temp_file  &&  mv temp_file  Input_file` and then try to run those commands too, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the files are gigantic 5+ gb, doing that would a really long operation.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock, I don't think it shouldn't take that much time, try it once and let us know then?

Comment: @AaronN.Brock: Could you show a few lines of sample to see how DOS endings look like?, just tested a file with with CRLF line terminators and `head -10` seemed to work fine

Comment: @lnian I think it might just be the CR line endings (as suggested in the first answer).  I'm not 100% sure how to output the file line endings.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock: do `cat -v <bigfile>` and post its few lines as input

Comment: @lnian Okay, it prints out a huge mess of data that's kinda unimportant, but it for the line endings in prints out `^M`'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wouldn't happen with Windows line endings, which are `CRLF`, since Unix uses `LF`. So the `LF` would still be seen and used.

What you're describing would happen if the line endings were just `CR` without `LF`. You can translate this with:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file.dat | head -10 | tr '\n' '\r'
```

The first `tr` converts to Unix format, and the second one translates back to the original format.

Comment: I'm getting `tr: extra operand ‘file.dat'` when i run that

Comment: You want `<` before `file.dat`. The `tr` command is unusual in that it doesn't accept a file name argument.

Comment: OP apparently wants the output to have windows line endings still

Comment: @Inian Correct, unfortunately, the output needs to still have the original endings.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock I added that a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: @Barmar Okay neat, that works.  However, I was wondering, wouldn't the `tr` have to do the replace in the entire file?

Comment: @Inian There are no newlines in the original file, just `\r` characters instead.

Comment: @AaronN.Brock No. `head` will exit after reading 10 lines, which closes the read end of the pipe. `tr` will then get an error when trying to write to the pipe, and it will exit.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use vim:

```
   vim foo.txt +"%s/\r/\r/g" +wq
```

This will replace all carriage returns.